# TypeError: Cannot read property 'width' of undefined when using ImageBackground

Tags: reactjs, react-native, imagebackground

I am using the [ImageBackground](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/imagebackground)  component from React Native. However, no matter what style I choose the same error message always displays. The code looks as it follows:

```
  render() {
return (
  <ImageBackground
    source={require('./common/Background_image.png')}
    stlye={styles.backgroundStyle}
  >
    <Text>Some text here!!</Text>
  </ImageBackground>
);
```

}

```
  backgroundStyle: {
flex: 1,
width: null,
height: null,
resizeMode: 'cover'}
```

[Image of the error here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UB9qB.png)

React-Native version:
react-native-cli: 2.0.1
react-native: 0.55.4

Any ideas of what this may happen?

Comment: why do you pass `width: null, height: null,`. Just delete it and try again.

Comment: Already tried that but I still obtain the same error

Answer (score 7):

You are passing `stlye` but the correct syntax should be `style`

```
<ImageBackground
    source={require('./common/Background_image.png')}
    style={styles.backgroundStyle}
>
  <Text>Some text here!!</Text>
</ImageBackground>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I spent like 2 hours with this silly mistake!